# Uninstall preinstalled apps in Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: software-uninstall, 23.10, app-center

Why can't I see all installed apps in the App Center under "Manage", and how do I now uninstall all apps I do not want, e.g. all games, "Videos" etc.? It seem like Canonical has made it unnecessarily difficult to change what they have decided should be included in Ubuntu. I have tried to uninstall using termional but then I need to find exactly what each app is called e.g. remove/uninstall Vidoes "no such package can be found"

Answer (score 3):

You should use their package names.

Open the terminal, and run `dpkg --list` to find out what their package names are.

Now look for unnecessary packages and remove them with the command:

```
sudo apt remove package-name
```

And then you can do the cleanup:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Thank you! I have been away from Linux for a few years that I simply could not think about the list of commands I should look up.